# RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Bot:chat_id:dispatcher' in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, runtime-error, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I have a problem in python-telgram-bot . RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Bot:chat_id:dispatcher'.I don't know what is this runtime error.Please help me
my code is this :

```
from threading import Thread
from telegram import update
import io
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty
import csv
import telethon
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

token = "TOKEN"


def start_handler(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    first_name = update.message.chat.first_name
    last_name = update.message.chat.last_name
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    api_id = API_ID
    api_hash = 'API_HASH'
    phone = 'PHONENUMBER'
    client =  TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
         client.send_code_request(phone)
         client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    # get all the channels that I can access
    channels = {d.entity.username: d.entity
                      for d in client.get_dialogs()
                      if d.is_channel}
    # choose the one that I want list users from
    channel = channels['CHANNELID']
    # get all the users and print them
    member_list = []
    for u in client.get_participants(channel):
         member_list.append([u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username])
    print(member_list)
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
updater = Updater(token)
start_command = CommandHandler('start', start_handler)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_command)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

but because of this code :

```
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    api_id = API_ID
    api_hash = 'API_HASH'
    phone = 'PHONENUMBER'
    client =  TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
         client.send_code_request(phone)
         client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    # get all the channels that I can access
    channels = {d.entity.username: d.entity
                      for d in client.get_dialogs()
                      if d.is_channel}
    # choose the one that I want list users from
    channel = channels['CHANNELID']
    # get all the users and print them
    member_list = []
    for u in client.get_participants(channel):
         member_list.append([u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.username])
    print(member_list)
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have RuntimeError like this:

> ```
> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Bot:chat_id:dispatcher'
> ```

what should i do?????

Comment: I have my CHANNELID , API_ID , API_HASH , PHONE NUMBER and you should try these with your self.

Comment: If possible, I recommend not mixing threaded and `asyncio` code. You should either use a threaded alternative to Telethon, or an `asyncio` alternative to PTB. For example, if you used Telethon for the bot too you would not have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as said in the error there is no event loop for asyncio to run in

so the solution is to simply create one
in your thread you should do this

```py
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
```

make sure you do this **INSIDE** the thread

the thread is created by pytelegrambot so i suggest monkey-patching the dispatch function for this or purely use telethon for your bot as well

Comment: where should I use this code in my code ???